# Migrate legacy PHP to PHP-FPM

Tags: linux, php, centos6, php-fpm

I wonder if I could have some feedback from some people that did the migration from php to PHP-FPM. The issue I have is that I have lots of scripts on the service. Some written by customers and I cant modify them all.

The reason I want to migrate to PHP-FPM is not particular about speed, but more because I was told that with PHP-FPM I can run 2 instances of PHP. So I am planing to run PHP5-FPM and PHP7-FPM and than slowly move and test the scripts on PHP7. But old scripts can still run on PHP5.

So this brings me to my 2 questions.
1. I run at the moment php56w 5.6.40-1.w6 package from Webtatic on a CentOS 6.10 server. When I install php5-fpm, do I have to make changes to all the scripts to work with the FPM version of PHP5?
2. Do you see any major complication to run 2 PHP-FPM instances on one server?

Thank you all for the feedback, this is a important decision for me and for me the dual install would be the perfect solution if I do not open the Pandora box by doing this.

Best wishes,
Thomas

Comment: you don't need to modify your script, because the client ask the php page to the webserver and the this one route the request to php-fpm and this one run your script using the php intepreter

Comment: Should read https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/ which is about switching to FPM and using Software Collections to allow multiple versions

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, this makes me more confident that I can do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Webtatic, if its possible to install both PHP version from them at the same time.

I would switch to Remi's RPM repo ( https://rpms.remirepo.net/) . If you enable remi-php56 , and update install to php-fpm ( which will be php 5.6 ) . Same repo contains php70-php-fpm , php71-php-fpm or php72-php-fpm. So install which ever you want in addition to php-fpm . The config for the second php-fpm instance will be in /etc/opt/remi/php7.x/. Replicate the other php fpm pool config to this, but change the ports ( ex run all php7.x pools on 10000+ port ). Then one by one switch the domains/virtualhosts to the new PHP by changing the port on fastcgi_pass .

Should work without complications, as long you have enough memory.

Comment: Thank you Sandor, this is valuable info and helps me a lot. Thank you for taking the time to help me.